Bechor Shor Al HaTorah
Can someone please recommend an edition of Bechor Shor Al HaTorah? I am looking for an accurate, all-Hebrew edition with clear print. If it it includes the text of the Humash, then great, but it is not a must.

Online: https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/R._Yosef_Bekhor_Shor/Bereshit/1.1#m4e2n6.  This is from alhatorah.org, an absolutely fabulous website
In print: https://mosadharavkook.com/shop/%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99-%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3-%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94/

Can you recommend a print version as well?

It is in stock here https://seforimplace.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=4479
